# sorting a array data structure using selection sort, but it’s not working

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures

How do I sort using priority from left to right. Values of priority if 1-3.

```
#include <iostream>
Using namespace std;

Struct patient{
Char name[30];
Int priority;
}s[10;
```

in main function I’m taking input using for loop I need to arrange them using int priority from left to right order

The original question is :
Write a c++ program for getting records of the patients of a hospital and arranges the patient based on the priority NO, the patient with low priority should be aligned left, the ones with high priority aligned to the right. This program should use array data structure and selection for sorting records.

I’d be really grateful you someone can help

Comment: When writing code, please don't use a word-processor (or similar) that capitalizes the first letter of every line. Also please learn how to create a [mcve] of *your own* attempt and show it to us, together with a description of the problems you have with the code. And also please take some time to read [ask]  as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There's no sorting code here, so we can't help fixing it.

Comment: As for sorting a generic standard container of user-defined structures, there must be thousands of examples and tutorials all over the Internet, and just as many questions here on Stack Overflow. What have you tried searching for? What did you find?

Comment: I’ve searched every possible place but I haven’t found anything

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of transforming your code to perform sorting

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct patient{
char name[30];
int priority;
bool operator>(const patient& rhs) const { return priority > rhs.priority; }
}s[10];

int main()
{
    std::sort(s, s + 10, std::greater<patient>());


    return 0;
}
```

Use `std::less` instead of `std::greater` if you want to sort least to greatest (you will have to define `operator<` instead of `operator>`)

Comment: I’m restricted to using the selection sort algorithm for sorting the structure.

Comment: @NikKhail Then edit your question to tell us what you have tried and what problems you have with your attempt? Is it the selection sort algorithm? Is it the sorting together with your own structure? Is it something else? Besides the links in my first comment, also please  read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour].